# Obtener el valor de un campo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript

```
<script>
function basePrice(event) {
   // Obtener contenedor padre (TR)
   let tr = event.target.closest('tr');
   // Obtener campos necesarios desde TR
   var width = tr.querySelector('[name="width[]"]').value;
   var height = tr.querySelector('[name="height[]"]').value;
   var quantity = tr.querySelector('[name="quantity[]"]').value;
   try{
       width = (isNaN(parseInt(width)))? 0 : parseInt(width);
       height = (isNaN(parseInt(height)))? 0 : parseInt(height);
       quantity = (isNaN(parseInt(quantity)))? 0 : parseInt(quantity);
       metros_lineales = (width/1000) * 180000;
       metros_cuadrados = (width * height) / 1000000;
       subtotal = metros_cuadrados * 100000;
       total = metros_lineales + subtotal + 480000 * 1,025;
       tr.querySelector('[name="unit_price[]"]').value = total;
       tr.querySelector('[name="total_price[]"]').value = total * quantity;
   }
   catch(e) {}
}
```

Formulario

```
<div class="table-responsive-sm">
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'invoice.store', 'name' => 'invoice']) !!}

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sistema</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th>Ancho (mm)</th>
                <th>Alto (mm)</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Precio Unitario</th>
                <th>Precio Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="form">
            <tr>
                <td>{{ Form::text('type[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('description[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('width', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onkeyup' => 'basePrice()']) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('height', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onkeyup' => 'basePrice()']) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('quantity', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onkeyup' => 'basePrice()']) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('unit_price', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Form::text('total_price', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
   <div class="form-row">
       <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pb-4 text-center">
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary add_button col-md-2 col-xs-12"> Agregar Ítem</a>
       </div>
   </div>
            
   <div class="col-12 mt-4 text-center"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Generar Cotización</button></div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

En otra tabla, fuera del `tr` del anterior formulario, tengo los totales generales, impuesto, etc... En este intento obtener el valor del campo `total_price` pero no lo obtengo

```
<table class="table table-clear">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><input type="text" name="total" class="form-control" id="total"  style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>Descuento (16%)</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><input type="text" name="discount" class="form-control"  id="discount" value="16" style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>Total Neto</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><input type="text" name="neto" class="form-control"  id="neto" style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>IVA</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><input type="text" name="tax" class="form-control" id="tax" style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>Total Pago</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><strong><input type="text" name="general_total" class="form-control" id="general_total" style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></strong></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Uso este script para tratar de obtenerlo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    //TOTAL
    var total = $("#total_price").val();
    $('#total').val(total);

    //NETO
    var total = $("#total").val();
    var discount = $("#discount").val();
    var subneto = ((total*discount)/100);
    var neto = (parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(subneto));

    $('#neto').val(neto);

    //TAX
    var tax = 16;
    var tax = ((tax*neto)/100);

    $('#tax').val(tax);

    //GENERAL TOTAL
    var general_total = (parseFloat(tax) + parseFloat(neto));

    $('#general_total').val(general_total);
});
```

NOTA: El campo `total_price[]` es un array, cuando imprimo el valor con `console.log` aunque tenga varios campos `total_price[]` completados me muestra solo uno y no el total, aunque el problema de momento es poder obtener el valor del campo en el otro formulario.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="kDjxb8qGwr5zdBQ5cDNB1gC4yKRu18ZzVTz6AJNO">

<title>Cotizador</title>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">

<main class="py-4">
        
<div class="content mt-5">
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <strong>Cotización #</strong> 525141 
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <span class="float-right">Viernes, 9 de octubre del 2020</span>

            <div class="row mb-4">

            </div>

            <div class="table-responsive-sm">

            <form method="POST" action="http://budget.com/dashboard/budgets/store" accept-charset="UTF-8" name="invoice"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="kDjxb8qGwr5zdBQ5cDNB1gC4yKRu18ZzVTz6AJNO">

                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sistema</th>
                            <th>Descripción</th>
                            <th>Ancho (mm)</th>
                            <th>Alto (mm)</th>
                            <th>Cantidad</th>
                            <th>Precio Unitario</th>
                            <th>Precio Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="item">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-2"><input class="form-control" name="type[]" type="text" value="Sistema #1"></td>
                            <td class="col-3"><input class="form-control" title="Sistema de Cortinas Plegable Glasscurtains. Aluminio color VARIABLE. Cristal Templado Incoloro de 10mm. Son VARIABLE Cristales." name="description[]" type="text" value="Sistema de Cortinas Plegable Glasscurtains. Aluminio color VARIABLE. Cristal Templado Incoloro de 10mm. Son VARIABLE Cristales."></td>
                            <td class="col-1"><input class="form-control" onkeyup="basePrice(event)" name="width[]" type="text"></td>
                            <td class="col-1"><input class="form-control" onkeyup="basePrice(event)" name="height[]" type="text"></td>
                            <td class="col-1"><input class="form-control" onkeyup="basePrice(event)" name="quantity[]" type="text"></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" name="unit_price[]" type="text"></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" name="total_price[]" type="text"></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove_button" title="Remove field"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pb-4 text-center">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary add_button col-md-2 col-xs-12"> Agregar Ítem</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row col-lg-8 justify-content-center align-items-center minh-100">

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-5 ml-auto">
                    <table class="table table-clear">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><input type="text" name="total" class="form-control" id="total"  style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>Descuento (16%)</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><input type="text" name="discount" class="form-control"  id="discount" value="16" style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>Total Neto</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><input type="text" name="neto" class="form-control"  id="neto" style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>IVA</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><input type="text" name="tax" class="form-control" id="tax" style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>Total Pago</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><strong><input type="text" name="general_total" class="form-control" id="general_total" style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></strong></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    let system = 1;
    var maxField = 16;
    var addButton = $('.add_button');
    var wrapper = $('.item');
    var fieldHTML = 
        '<tr>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<input type="text" id="type[]" name="type[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Sistema #'+ system +'" value="Sistema #">' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<input type="text" id="description[]" name="description[]" class="form-control" title="Texto a mostrar" value="Sistema de Cortinas Plegable Glasscurtains. Aluminio color VARIABLE. Cristal Templado Incoloro de 10mm. Son VARIABLE Cristales.">' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<input type="text" id="width[]" name="width[]" class="form-control" onKeyUp="basePrice(event)">' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<input type="text" id="height[]" name="height[]" class="form-control" onKeyUp="basePrice(event)">' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<input type="text" id="quantity[]" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" onKeyUp="basePrice(event)">' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<input type="text" id="unit_price[]" name="unit_price[]" class="form-control">' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<input type="text" id="total_price[]" name="total_price[]" class="form-control">' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove_button" title="Remove field"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></a>' +
            '</td>' +
        '<tr>'; 

    $(addButton).click(function () {
        system++;
        return system;
    });

    var x = 1;
    $(addButton).click(function () {
        if (x < maxField) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML);
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        x--;
    });
});
</script>

<script>
function basePrice(event) {
   // Obtener contenedor padre (TR)
   let tr = event.target.closest('tr');
   // Obtener campos necesarios desde TR
   var width = tr.querySelector('[name="width[]"]').value;
   var height = tr.querySelector('[name="height[]"]').value;
   var quantity = tr.querySelector('[name="quantity[]"]').value;
   try{
       width = (isNaN(parseInt(width)))? 0 : parseInt(width);
       height = (isNaN(parseInt(height)))? 0 : parseInt(height);
       quantity = (isNaN(parseInt(quantity)))? 0 : parseInt(quantity);
       metros_lineales = (width/1000) * 180000;
       metros_cuadrados = (width * height) / 1000000;
       subtotal = metros_cuadrados * 100000;
       total = metros_lineales + subtotal + 480000 * 1,025;
       tr.querySelector('[name="unit_price[]"]').value = total;
       tr.querySelector('[name="total_price[]"]').value = total * quantity;
   }
   catch(e) {}
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    //TOTAL
    var total = $("#total_price").val();
    $('#total').val(total);

    //NETO
    var total = $("#total").val();
    var discount = $("#discount").val();
    var subneto = ((total*discount)/100);
    var neto = (parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(subneto));

    $('#neto').val(neto);

    //TAX
    var tax = 16;
    var tax = ((tax*neto)/100);

    $('#tax').val(tax);

    //GENERAL TOTAL
    var general_total = (parseFloat(tax) + parseFloat(neto));

    $('#general_total').val(general_total);
});

</script>


    </main>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún marco de trabajo (framework) para la interfaz? ¿Algo como Angular, Vue, etc? No veo ningún campo cuya `id` sea `total_price`, ¿dónde está? Sin ese campo el cálculo `$("#total_price").val();` no hace nada. ¿Podrías compartir el HTML generado en vez del de la plantilla?

Comment: Es este campo `{{ Form::text('total_price[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}` está en el primer formulario

Comment: Pero eso no es ni HTML ni javascript. Creo que eso es el motor de plantillas de Laravel, que genera una etiqueta `<input type="text">` cuyo atributo `name` valdrá `total_price[]`, pero en ningún momento estás definiendo una ID, por lo que sigue sin existir dicha ID.

Comment: Tienes la opción de calcular ese valor en el lado de PHP o bien en Javascript. Yo, personalmente, te recomiendo hacerlo en el lado de PHP, pero para eso necesitamos el código del controlador.

Comment: @Oscar me percaté y le agregué el ID al campo y sigue sin funcionar, los valores no los lee desde la base de datos, los calcula a medida que el usuario los carga en los campos

Comment: Entonces, ¿me estás diciendo que tienes multitud de campos que comparten el mismo `id`? ¿Podrías compartir el HTML que genera la plantilla para conocer EXACTAMENTE cómo debemos buscar en javascript los campos generados?

Comment: Okey, estoy agregando el `html` en la pregunta, lo puedes ejecutar y ver como funciona, agrego dinamicamente los itmes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema es que `var total = $("#total_price").val();` te va a devolver solo un elemento, es por eso que, de acuerdo a lo mencionado en tu otra pregunta, todos los campos que se repiten deben tener corchetes, para que sean tratados como arreglo y no les asignes ID, este debe ser único.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sistema</th>
            <th>Descripción</th>
            <th>Ancho (mm)</th>
            <th>Alto (mm)</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>Precio Unitario</th>
            <th>Precio Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="form">
        <tr>
            <td>{{ Form::text('type[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
            <td>{{ Form::text('description[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
            <td>{{ Form::text('width[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onkeyup' => 'basePrice(event)']) }}</td>
            <td>{{ Form::text('height[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onkeyup' => 'basePrice(event)']) }}</td>
            <td>{{ Form::text('quantity[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'onkeyup' => 'basePrice(event)']) }}</td>
            <td>{{ Form::text('unit_price[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
            <td>{{ Form::text('total_price[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Cada que se realicen cálculos de precio puedes ejecutar la función para también calcular total, descuento, impuesto y total general, porque, como lo tienes ahora: `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` solo se va a ejecutar al cargar la página.

```js
function basePrice(event) {
   // Obtener contenedor padre (TR)
   let tr = event.target.closest('tr');
   // Obtener campos necesarios desde TR
   var width = tr.querySelector('[name="width[]"]').value;
   var height = tr.querySelector('[name="height[]"]').value;
   try{
       width = (isNaN(parseInt(width)))? 0 : parseInt(width);
       height = (isNaN(parseInt(height)))? 0 : parseInt(height);
       metros_lineales = (width/1000) * 180000;
       metros_cuadrados = (width * height) / 1000000;
       subtotal = metros_cuadrados * 100000;
       total = metros_lineales + subtotal * 1,025;
       // Establecer precio
       tr.querySelector('[name="unit_price[]"]').value = total + 480000;
       // Obtener cantidad
       var quantity = parseInt(tr.querySelector('[name="quantity[]"]').value) || 0;
       // Calcular total
       tr.querySelector('[name="total_price[]"]').value = (total + 480000) * quantity;
       // Ejecutar función para calcular totales
       calculaTotal();
   }
   catch(e) {}
}

function calculaTotal() {
    // Inicializar total en cero
    var total = 0;
    // Obtener totales de cada elemento
    var total_price = document.querySelectorAll('[name="total_price[]"]');
    // Recorrer para sumar a total
    total_price.forEach(subt => total += parseInt(subt.value) || 0);

    // Asignar valor al input
    document.querySelector('#total').value = total;
    // Obtener descuento
    discount = parseInt(document.querySelector('#discount').value) || 0;
    var subneto = (total * discount) / 100;
    var neto = parseFloat(total - subneto);
    document.querySelector('#neto').value = neto;

    // Calcular impuesto
    var taxRate = 16;
    var tax = (neto * taxRate) / 100;
    document.querySelector('#tax').value = tax;

    // Total general
    var general_total = parseFloat(neto + tax);
    document.querySelector('#general_total').value = general_total;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sistema</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Ancho (mm)</th>
                    <th>Alto (mm)</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Precio Unitario</th>
                    <th>Precio Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="form">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="type[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="description[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="width[]" onkeyup="basePrice(event);"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="height[]" onkeyup="basePrice(event);"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" onkeyup="basePrice(event);"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="unit_price[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="total_price[]"></td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="type[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="description[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="width[]" onkeyup="basePrice(event);"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="height[]" onkeyup="basePrice(event);"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" onkeyup="basePrice(event);"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="unit_price[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="total_price[]"></td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
    <table class="table table-clear">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><input type="text" name="total" class="form-control" id="total"  style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>Descuento (16%)</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><input type="text" name="discount" class="form-control"  id="discount" value="16" style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>Total Neto</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><input type="text" name="neto" class="form-control"  id="neto" style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>IVA</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><input type="text" name="tax" class="form-control" id="tax" style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left"><strong>Total Pago</strong></td>
                                <td class="right"><strong><input type="text" name="general_total" class="form-control" id="general_total" style="cursor: pointer;" readonly></strong></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

**Importante:** Omití el uso de jQuery, porque con javascript puro:

- No agregas toda una librería para operaciones simples
- Me parece más legible
- Fue la opción con la que te respondí en la otra pregunta

Pero, si todavía quieres usar jQuery, te dejo unos ejemplos para saber cómo adaptar el código:

Acceder a un elemento por ID:

> Javascript puro: `document.querySelector('#total')`
> jQuery: `$('#total')`

Acceder a colección de elementos por atributo:

> Js: `document.querySelectorAll('[name="total_price[]"]')`
> jQ: `$('[name="total_price[]"]')`

Obtener TR a partir del evento:

> Js: `let tr = event.target.closest('tr');`
> jQ: `let tr = $(event.target).closest('tr');`

Obtener campo y valor a partir de TR:

> Js: `var width = tr.querySelector('[name="width[]"]').value;`
> jQ: `var width = $(tr).find('[name="width[]"]').val();`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Triby nuevamente, ya lo reviso.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias... y la explicación también.

Comment: Hola @Triby trato de hacer la suma de todos los campos de `width[]` de la misma manera que con el precio total, `var total_width = 0;
        var total_width = document.querySelectorAll('[name="width[]"]');
        total_width.forEach(total_width => total_width += parseInt(total_width.value) || 0);` y me muestra estoen vez del total: `[object NodeList]`

Comment: Estás usando la misma variable para sumar total y para recorrer los elementos.

Comment: Gracias, fue un error, los había puesto así en un momento y con ctrl z lo regresé y no me percaté... Era porque estaba asignando al value una variable que no correspondía.